# Вращение элементов по оси с остановкой ровно по центру

Tags: javascript

Есть N число Элементов, которые вращаются по окружности
Нужно остановить вращение через N промежуток времени(7сек), так что бы этот определенный элемент оказался ровно по (центру)

Вот тут есть рабочий вариант но он останавливается не ровно
https://jsfiddle.net/mario34/qxq1yd0c/

Подскажите как рассчитать это

```
var pos = $('#center').position(),
    elements = $('.div').length,
    speed = 7,
  radiusSat = $('.div').eq(0).width() / 2,
  radius = $('#center').width() / 2,
  cx = pos.left + radius,
  cy = pos.top + radius,
  x, y, angle = 0, angles = [],
  spc = 360 / elements,
  deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
  interval,
  i = 0;

for(;i < elements; i++) {
    angle += spc;
    angles.push({
        'angle': angle,
        'elem': $('.div').eq(i)
    });

}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat + 10);

loop();

function loop() {

    step = 1 / 60;
    speed -= step;

    if(speed <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
    for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

        angle = angles[i].angle;

        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
        y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

        $('.div').eq(i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

        angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle + speed;
        if (angles[i].angle > 360) angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle - 360;
    }
}

interval = setInterval(loop,17);
```

Comment: Задача решена? Если нет, то попробуй selected переставить на следующий div и строчку if (angles[i].angle > 360) angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle - 360; заменить на if (angles[i].angle > 360) angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle - 360 - speed; В таком варианте красный кружек становится посредине, но там есть всеже баг((( Но может это наталкнет на какую-то мысль тебя)))))